# Low FPS when using SKSPriteNode as the background image

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In the iOS simulator.
when I use the SKSpriteNode as the background image in the SKScene, FPS becomes about 30.
But when I use SKScene's backgroundColor property instead of image, FPS keeps about 60.

The background image size is 33KB, 568 * 320px.
In the case of @2x , size is 90KB, 1136 * 640px.
(My application is Landscape Mode)

In the iPhone5,  FPS keeps about 60 at the same condition.

Is it correct behavior?
Or is there something wrong in my approach to show background image.

Comment: Simulators are dependant on your mac hardware, and usually performer worse in games then devices.For performance you should trust your device :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulators are dependent on your Mac hardware and usually perform worse than devices. For true performance you should use your device. :)